# Looking to create a Dynamic Modifier, not returning the necessary type

Tags: swift, swiftui

So the idea is to have a modifier that depending on the `Style`

```swift
   enum Style {
       case classic
       case jumbo
       case minimalist
   }
```

Will give me a simple modifier for my buttons..

Here is what I have so far..

```
    struct DynamicModifier: ViewModifier {
       let style: Style
       func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        switch style {
        case .classic:
            return content
                .padding(.vertical, 5)
                .padding(.horizontal)
        case .jumbo:
            return content
                .padding()
        case .minimalist:
            return content
                     }
           }
        }
```

This is the error: `Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types`

And Xcode is right, I'm not returning the appropriate return type. But I'm not sure what to return here honestly.. I can't return `ViewModifier` because of the famous associatedType generic constraint error.. I've also tried returning `ModifiedContent`.

I'm at my wits end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `@ViewBuilder` to the signature and remove the return statements this gives the same functionality that we're used to seeing in, for example, a regular SwiftUI `View`'s `body`:

```
struct DynamicModifier: ViewModifier {
    let style: Style
    @ViewBuilder func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        switch style {
        case .classic:
            content
                .padding(.vertical, 5)
                .padding(.horizontal)
        case .jumbo:
            content
                .padding()
        case .minimalist:
            content
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Simplistically simple !  Thanks